# Add a class On Click - JS Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 Tabs, with a class `'fetch_records'`. When the user clicks on the other Tab, the clicked tab should get activated by adding the new class `'years_active'` and other should remain same and the class `'years_active'` get removed if any.

My code for that is :

```
$('.fetch_records').click(function (e) {
    $('.fetch_records').removeClass('years_active');
    $(this).addClass('years_active');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ajax-loader').show();
    var year = $(this).attr('data-year');

    $.ajax({
        ...Do SOmething...

        success: function (msg) {
            ...show success message...
        }
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<li><a data-year="2001" class="fetch_records years_active"> 2001 <a/> </li>
<li><a data-year="2002" class="fetch_records"> 2002 <a/> </li>
<li><a data-year="2003" class="fetch_records"> 2003 <a/> </li>
```

Comment: Use: `$('.fetch_records').removeClass('years_active');` before add class

Comment: Your closing anchor tags are malformed.

Comment: I had already used the code $('.fetch_records').removeClass('years_active'); before the addClass('years_active')

Comment: Works fine if you fix your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jmk9k9aL/

Comment: Take care: yours JS, if it isn't declared inside a `document` ready handler, must be declared **AFTER** the HTML.

Answer (score -3):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this part of your code, it runs perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/fnp27nng/1/

Even though your markup **is** malformed - as pointed out by just about everyone -, your problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Try checking the javascript console for errors.

**JavaScript**

```
$('.fetch_records').click(function(e) {
    $('.fetch_records').removeClass('years_active');
    $(this).addClass('years_active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fetch_records {
    background: #EEE;
}
.years_active {
    background: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a data-year="2001" class="fetch_records years_active">2001</a></li>
<li><a data-year="2002" class="fetch_records">2002</a></li>
<li><a data-year="2003" class="fetch_records">2003</a></li>
```

Comment: why is this an answer?...it is nothing more than a comment that the code shown works